# Using Spatial Analyst Sample tool

Tags: arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, sampling

I have a bunch of rasters and a point file.  I need the information from ll the raster files to be added to my points.

My usual workflow is to use the Spatial Analyst sample tool.  It works fine and I can do a spatial join to get the information added to the point file.  However, furstratingly the sample tool never seems to offer useful field headings and with a lot of rasters it can become confusing as to which value relates to which raster.  Does anyone know of a script or workaround that can produce a table with field headings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this in a model or script you can [add a field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Add_Field/001700000047000000/), [calculate the field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) with the *grid_code* (or whatever field it creates) and then [delete](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Delete_Field/00170000004n000000/) the *grid_code* field. That way everything goes into a properly named field and the default name field is gone!

Answer (score 2):

The ArcToolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools > Extraction > [Extract Multi Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002s000000) tool assigns multiple rasters values to a point feature class and assigns the raster name as the column name(s).

Comment: That's a neater solution to this problem. I like it. No flexibility though, if you've got multiple rasters called the same thing what happens there?

Comment: How would you otherwise account for an identical raster naming convention? I guess you could use a counter in a script to add an increment value to a filename but this seems like a poor way to manage data and an outlier occurrence. I have never tried it but I imagine that ESRI added an error handling routine that creates a new name if it already exist in the point attribute table.

Comment: I reckon give the rasters sensible names first. An ounce of preparation... Grid rasters by file limitations have short names and can be identical but of different times/scenes which would cause this situation to occur. Shapefiles have a limit on attribute name lengths. With this in mind give the rasters sensible names first and then there's no problem to fix is there.

Comment: It's worth remembering that you're limited to 13 (or 15, I forget) characters for field headings if your table is going into a geodatabase.

Comment: A 10 character field name limitation for shapefiles. Legacy of the dbf format. ESRI file geodatabase field name lengths can be 64 characters, see: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018s00000002000000